# GSA Wrapper in java?

Tags: java, word-wrap, google-search-appliance

Does anybody knows a good wrapper implementation for Google Search Appliance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a look: http://gsa-japi.sourceforge.net/gsa-japi.html